# If else verbose currency statement

Tags: ruby, liquid

I want to create an if/else statement that prints the verbose total differently depending on whether there is a value after a decimal point.

Case Examples:

- The value is 395

  The statement prints `three hundred and ninety five baht only`.
- The value is 395.50

  The statement prints `three hundred and ninety five baht and fifty satang`.

I cannot calculate and print the values after the decimal point, which I described as reminder calculation.

```
{% if folio.total != folio.total | floor %} {{ folio.verbose_total }} baht only {% else %} {{ folio.verbose_total | floor}} baht and {{ folio.verbose_total | remainder calculation}} satang {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an error in your if statement. You might try writing the comparison as:

```
if folio.total != (folio.total).floor
```

The parentheses might be extraneous, not positive, but they won't make it wrong. I don't know what the " | " operator does in that statement. All I could find is that it is used as a binary OR operator.